Android Studio Ladybug compatibility with AGP 8.7.2
I just downloaded the latest version of Android Studio Ladybug.  Looks like this version comes bundled w/ Java 21.  When I open my project the AGP upgrade assistant wants me to upgrade to AGP 8.7.2.  When I try to upgrade with the assitant I get the following error:
No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.

Current compiler settings

Looking at the compatibility matrix possible that AGP 8.7.x is not compatible w/ Java 21?  If that is really the case and Android Studio Ladybug comes bundled with Java 21 AND, I am running Java 21, why in the world would the AGP assistant want me to upgrade to 8.7.2.
Am I missing something here?  Anyone else running AGP 8.7.2 with Java 21 in ladybug?

Whomever with the down vote a comment on why would be helpful.  Can I run AGP 8.7.2 with Java 21 in Android Studio Ladybug?

I've got the same problem after updating my Android Studio to Ladybug (yes, bug)
Try to

download and install JDK 17
set JAVA_HOME environment variable
set GRADLE JDK in Android Studio (Settings -> Build, Ex... -> Build Tools -> Gradle) to that location
and try again.


Are you running AGP 8.7.2?
